# Can't read metadata field with Exif

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, metadata, exif

I'm getting images that have their 'UserComment' field equals to 'Encrypted' or equals to 'Decrypted'.
I need to activate a function depends on it's value.
For reading the metadata I'm using https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/blob/master/exif.js.
I succeeded to read the 'Make' field with:

```
        var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
```

but I don't succeed to read the field named 'UserComment' that has the data I need to read.
My code is:

```
const getExif = (image) => {
    EXIF.getData(image, function () {
        var userComment = EXIF.getTag(this, "UserComment");
        return userComment != undefined;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello. Read your question and I couldn't get what is the problem since there is no simulation or code to execute or img file. Reasons could be many like function not executed or img file which doesn't provide UserComment or CORS problem. Could you add more details?

Comment: I can get the Make/Model field but can't get UserComment field.

Comment: Hello Tomer, can you maybe provide the image so we can test it?